# Fetch the values using debug module in ansible..!

Tags: shell, azure, scripting, ansible, coding-style

```
register: dnsfact 
- debug: var=dnsfact.ansible_facts.azure_dnszones[0].name
```

If I debug like above, I am getting the below output:

```
ok: [openshift-infra01.example.net] => {
    "dnsfact.ansible_facts.azure_dnszones[0].name": "226********"
```

- `debug: var=dnsfact.ansible_facts.azure_dnszones[1].name` > this will give me two values.
- `debug: var=dnsfact.ansible_facts.azure_dnszones[2].name` > this will give me three values.

If I want to print all the values, which value do I need to pass? I tried with `dnszones[:]` and `dnszones[':']`. But I am not able to fetch the values.

please find the actual output below.

```
 "dnsfact.ansible_facts.azure_dnszones": [
         {
             "etag": "00000002-0000-0000-9ed1-be810a8bd401",
             "id": "/subscription*****/dnszones/226.10.in-addr.arpa",
             "location": "global",
             "name": "226.10.in-addr.arpa",
```

From this output we are trying to filter the "name".

Comment: @nwinkler

The output is provided below.

"dnsfact.ansible_facts.azure_dnszones": [
        {
            "etag": "00000002-0000-0000-9ed1-be810a8bd401",
            "id": "/subscriptions/********/resourceGroups/exp1/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnszones/226.10.in-addr.arpa",
            "location": "global",
            "name": "226.10.i*******",

Comment: Added in the question itself. @nwinkler

Comment: The data you added in the question is incomplete - the object is not closed and there's only one incomplete item in the array. Things like `azure_dnszones[2]` will not work with the above data.

Comment: What i am trying to say is, If i give - debug: var=dnsfact.ansible_facts.azure_dnszones[0].name, this is filtering only one value. In my environment i have many sub sets. In each subset i have to filter the value for name. @nwinkler

Comment: Please provide an example for that - it's hard to answer your question without a full example.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the [`map` jinja2 filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#builtin-filters):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ dnsfact.ansible_facts.azure_dnszones | map(attribute="name") | list }}"
```

Its job is to do almost the same thing that python's `map` does, but more targeted toward attribute extraction than just arbitrary computation over a list. You'll (usually) need that `| list` at the end because `map()` is lazy and returns a generator, which needs to be evaluated if you just want to see the output